# Why numpy is slower than pure python?

Tags: python, numpy, math

I try to implement the Gauss Elimination in python.
I expected that Using numpy is faster than pure python.

So, As a result, the result of 'Backward Elimination' is understand.
And when I use 100X100 matrix In 'Forward Elimination', numpy is faster than pure python. 
But, when I use 1000X1000 matrix, It doesn't make sense in 'Forward Elimination'.

why numpy is slower than pure python?
It make me confused. 

Implement

```
def foward_elimination(A, b):
    A = A.copy().astype(np.float64); b = b.copy().astype(np.float64)
    for i_pivot in range(len(A)-1):
        for j_target in range(i_pivot+1, len(A)):
            b[j_target] = b[j_target] - (A[j_target,i_pivot] / A[i_pivot,i_pivot] * b[i_pivot])
            A[j_target] = A[j_target] - (A[j_target,i_pivot] / A[i_pivot,i_pivot] * A[i_pivot])
    return A, b   

def backward_elimination(A, b):
    b = b.copy()
    for i in range(len(A)-1, -1, -1):
        for j in range(len(A)-1, i, -1):
            b[i] -= A[i,j]*b[j]
        b[i] = b[i] / A[i,i]
    return b

def custom_foward_elimination(A, b):
    A = A.copy().astype(np.float64); b = b.copy().astype(np.float64)
    for i_pivot in range(len(A)-1):
        b[i_pivot+1:] = b[i_pivot+1:] - (A[i_pivot+1:,i_pivot] / A[i_pivot,i_pivot] * b[i_pivot])
        A[i_pivot+1:] = A[i_pivot+1:] - (A[i_pivot+1:,i_pivot].reshape(-1,1).repeat(len(A), axis=1) / A[i_pivot,i_pivot] * A[i_pivot])
    return A, b

def custom_backward_elimination(A, b):
    sol = np.ones(len(A))
    for i in np.arange(len(A)-1, -1, -1):
        sol[i] = (b[i] - (A[i]*sol)[i+1:].sum()) / A[i, i]

def gauss_solve(A, b):
    A_foward, b_foward = foward_elimination(A, b)
    sol = backward_elimination(A_foward, b_foward)
    return sol

def custom_gauss_solve(A, b):
    A_foward, b_foward = custom_foward_elimination(A, b)
    sol = custom_backward_elimination(A_foward, b_foward)
    return sol
```

Test (In google colab)

```
for n in [2,5,10,100,1000]:
    A = np.random.rand(n,n)
    b = np.random.rand(n)

    print('=== {} Dimension ==='.format(n))

    print('- Forward Elimination -')
    %timeit -n 30 -r 1 forward_elimination(A, b)
    print('- Forward Elimination (Using numpy) -')
    %timeit -n 30 -r 1 custom_foward_elimination(A, b)

    A_forward, b_forward = forward_elimination(A, b)

    print('- Backward Elimination -')
    %timeit -n 30 -r 1 backward_elimination(A_forward, b_forward)
    print('- Backward Elimination (Using numpy) -')
    %timeit -n 30 -r 1 custom_backward_elimination(A_forward, b_forward)

    print()
```

Result

```
=== 2 Dimension ===
- Forward Elimination -
30 loops, best of 1: 14.2 µs per loop
- Forward Elimination (Using numpy) -
30 loops, best of 1: 37.5 µs per loop
- Backward Elimination -
30 loops, best of 1: 8.84 µs per loop
- Backward Elimination (Using numpy) -
30 loops, best of 1: 15.7 µs per loop

=== 5 Dimension ===
- Forward Elimination -
30 loops, best of 1: 58.6 µs per loop
- Forward Elimination (Using numpy) -
30 loops, best of 1: 52.6 µs per loop
- Backward Elimination -
30 loops, best of 1: 21.6 µs per loop
- Backward Elimination (Using numpy) -
30 loops, best of 1: 52 µs per loop

=== 10 Dimension ===
- Forward Elimination -
30 loops, best of 1: 178 µs per loop
- Forward Elimination (Using numpy) -
30 loops, best of 1: 109 µs per loop
- Backward Elimination -
30 loops, best of 1: 57.8 µs per loop
- Backward Elimination (Using numpy) -
30 loops, best of 1: 51.8 µs per loop

=== 100 Dimension ===
- Forward Elimination -
30 loops, best of 1: 18.3 ms per loop
- Forward Elimination (Using numpy) -
30 loops, best of 1: 4.05 ms per loop
- Backward Elimination -
30 loops, best of 1: 2.53 ms per loop
- Backward Elimination (Using numpy) -
30 loops, best of 1: 447 µs per loop

=== 1000 Dimension ===
- Forward Elimination -
30 loops, best of 1: 2.48 s per loop
- Forward Elimination (Using numpy) -
30 loops, best of 1: 4.42 s per loop ### ????
- Backward Elimination -
30 loops, best of 1: 257 ms per loop
- Backward Elimination (Using numpy) -
30 loops, best of 1: 5.51 ms per loop
```

Comment: `A[i_pivot+1:,i_pivot].reshape(-1,1).repeat(len(A), axis=1)` That looks like a lot of extra work for the `numpy` version. I'm not familiar with the problem space, though, so how to do this better (if indeed there is a way) is something I cannot answer.

Comment: Where's the pure Python?  `A` and `b` are created as arrays.  I don't see equivalent lists.  Usually iterating over an array is slower than iterating over an equivalent list.  Converting list to array also takes time.  But once created, whole array operations are usually faster.  Without getting into details, your `custom` versions seem to eliminate one level of iteration.

Comment: Thank you!<br>
As you mentioned, I refactoring the code.<br>
`A[i_pivot+1:,i_pivot].reshape(-1,1).repeat(len(A), axis=1)` to `A[i_pivot+1:,[i_pivot]]`.<br>
Now It works greatly better!